# Error using Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA to connect to Firebase from Arduino

Tags: firebase, arduino

I am using Arduino WiFi Rev2 for my explorations. I want to connect Arduino with Firebase. Using Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA, is giving me an error saying "Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA_HTTPClient.h: No such file or directory"

I have tried the following code which is provided as an example under FirebaseArduino Using WifiNINA library. For obvious reasons I am not including Wifi information and Firebase project information.

```
#include "Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA.h"
#define FIREBASE_HOST "YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "YOUR_FIREBASE_DATABASE_SECRET"
#define WIFI_SSID "YOUR_WIFI_AP"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD"

//Define Firebase data object
FirebaseData firebaseData;

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    status = WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  //Provide the autntication data
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);

  String path = "/UNO_WiFi_REV2_Test";
  String jsonStr;

  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println("----------Begin Set Test-----------");
  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {

    if (Firebase.setInt(firebaseData, path + "/Int/Data" + (i + 1), (i + 1) * 10))
    {
      Serial.println("----------Set result-----------");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
      Serial.print("VALUE: ");
      if (firebaseData.dataType() == "int")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.intData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "float")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.floatData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "boolean")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.boolData() == 1 ? "true" : "false");
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "string")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.stringData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "json")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.jsonData());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("----------Can't set data--------");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println("----------Begin Get Test-----------");
  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {

    if (Firebase.getInt(firebaseData, path + "/Int/Data" + (i + 1)))
    {
      Serial.println("----------Get result-----------");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
      Serial.print("VALUE: ");
      if (firebaseData.dataType() == "int")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.intData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "float")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.floatData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "boolean")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.boolData() == 1 ? "true" : "false");
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "string")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.stringData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "json")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.jsonData());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("----------Can't get data--------");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println("----------Begin Push Test----------");
  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

    if (Firebase.pushInt(firebaseData, path + "/Push/Int", (i + 1)))
    {
      Serial.println("----------Push result-----------");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.print("PUSH NAME: ");
      Serial.println(firebaseData.pushName());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("----------Can't push data--------");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  for (uint8_t i = 5; i < 10; i++)
  {

    jsonStr = "{\"Data" + String(i + 1) + "\":" + String(i + 1) + "}";

    if (Firebase.pushJSON(firebaseData, path + "/Push/Int", jsonStr))
    {
      Serial.println("----------Push result-----------");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.print("PUSH NAME: ");
      Serial.println(firebaseData.pushName());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("----------Can't push data--------");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println("---------Begin Update Test----------");
  Serial.println("-----------------------------------");
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

    jsonStr = "{\"Data" + String(i + 1) + "\":" + String(i + 5.5) + "}";

    if (Firebase.updateNode(firebaseData, path + "/Int", jsonStr))
    {
      Serial.println("----------Update result-----------");
      Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
      Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
      Serial.print("VALUE: ");
      if (firebaseData.dataType() == "int")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.intData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "float")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.floatData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "boolean")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.boolData() == 1 ? "true" : "false");
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "string")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.stringData());
      else if (firebaseData.dataType() == "json")
        Serial.println(firebaseData.jsonData());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("----------Can't Update data--------");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late, but I think I found out the problem.

The files for the *Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA_HTTPClient* in  **~/Arduino/libraries/Firebase_Arduino_based_on_WiFiNINA/src/** were named incorrectly (*Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA_HTTPC**L**ient* instead of *Firebase_Arduino_WiFiNINA_HTTPClient*).

Thus, you just have rename both the .h and .cpp files and it should work out.